# In python, is it possible to assign one of multiple variables with the same prefix to another variable dynamically?

Tags: python, dictionary

The question is about to getting one of multiple data in a run time. There are several data such as

```
dict_a = {'shape':1}
dict_b = {'opt':'sp'}
dict_c = ...
```

From the function with job of 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. Rather than using just long repetitive coding such as

```
if job == 'a':
    dic = dict_a
elif job == 'b':
    dic = dict_b
...
```

I want to write a more smart coding. I have tried this with exec, but this does not work.

```
def running(job):
    dictname = 'dict_'+job
    var = 'dic'
    exec("%s = %s" % (var, dictname))
    if "dic" in locals():
        print(f"True, {dic}")
```

"dic" seems to be made by exec() but cannot use dic. The error message goes as follows:

> print(f"True, {dic}")

> NameError: name 'dic' is not defined

Comment: Just make a dictonary of dictionaries

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/1324033)

Comment: This is not duplicated following the correct answer from SomeoneRandom3124. This not the problem for the variable for variables. The question is different and the answer is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dictionary of dictionaries is more efficient but another possible solution to this is the use of eval

```
>>> dict_a = {'shape':1}
>>> dict_b = {'opt':'sp'}
>>> job = "dict_a"
>>> dic = eval(job)
>>> dic
{'shape': 1}
```

Comment: job should be "a" not "dict_a".

Comment: you can replace job with `dictname` and that will give you what you need.  note this returns a reference so if you modify `dic` you are actually modifying `dict_a`

Comment: This looks more fancy: job is a string so it can change. And by eval(job), if there is job-variable, the job value(string, dict, any), that is object, is referenced by dic. It looks the one exactly which I was thinking. There is no the secondary dict, that is dict of dicts, if I have followed correctly.

Comment: I confirmed that this is working without making dict for dicts.

Comment: The function of eval() looks valuable. Once I have asked a question whether there is a preprocessor function of C in python and some experts said No. But in my thought, it might be possible that eval() can replace the the function of preprocessor such as (#ifdef #else #endif) in python.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary of dictionaries would be much easier:

```py
mega_dict = {'a': {'shape':1}, 'b' :{'opt':'sp'}}
print(mega_dict['a']['shape']) # or any other usage...
```

Comment: This is correct but following the question: mega_dict={'a':dict_a; 'b':dict_b, ...} then print(mega_dict[job])

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary consisting of all dictionaries. Something like this

```
final_dict = {'dict_a' : dict_a, 'dict_b' : dict_b}
```

Then in your `running` method, you can just simply do

```
dictname = 'dict_' + job
dic = final_dict[dictname]
```